# finish() from onPostExcute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My main activity class. A dialog box to accept a code and check it in async task

```
public class StatusPage extends ActionBarActivity {
...
   Context con = this;
   onCreate{
      ...
      DialogBox = new Dialog(v.getContext());
      DialogBox.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_content);
      DialogBox.show();
      Button btnOk= (Button) DialogBox 
                    .findViewById(R.id.button1);
      btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText text = (EditText) DialogBox 
                            .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String code = text.getText().toString();
            GetStatus gsobj = new GetStatus();
            gsobj.connect(code, con);
         }
       });
     }
   }
```

My async task class:

```
public class GetStatus{
...
   protected void connect(String code, Context con)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            new GetStatusTask(code, con)
                .execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/connect_gs.php?code="
                    + code);
         }

   private class GetStatusTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      Context con;
      String code;

      public GetStatusTask(String code, Context con) {
         this.con = con;
         this code = code;
      }
      protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
           //work in stealth mode
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         ...
         if(status == okay){
             //goto a new activity
             //finish the StatusPage activity so that it does not remain in stack
            Intent i = new Intent(con, HomePage.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            con.startActivity(i);
            ((Activity) con).finish();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Everything works fine except that I get an "application not responding" dialog box, after which I am able to see the HomePage as I want to. I get the error on this line:

```
((Activity) con).finish();
```

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.desigobuild2, PID: 3451
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at com.example.desigobuild2.GetUser$GetUserTask.onPostExecute(GetStatus.java:165)
at com.example.desigobuild2.GetUser$GetUserTask.onPostExecute(GetStatus.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I see that the error is in casting the context to Activity. How do I fix it?

Comment: initialize con = this; inside onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
((Activity) con).finish();
```

to

```
((StatusPage ) con).finish();
```

Comment: It seems to work I guess. But get error in the line "ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this)" for HomePage.java. I bet the problem is using "this" now. Will have to figure out what. Thank you for helping out :)

Comment: Instead of `this`, use `HomePage.this`

Comment: Use activity context in place of `this`. In which `Activity` are you calling this?

Comment: I am creating a dynamic scrollView in `code`HomePage`code` activity. Using `code`ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(HomePage.this);`code` or simply `code`this`code` in `code`onCreate()`code` there gives an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56811/discussion-between-andro-and-jungleboy).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are casting to common Activity class instead your StatusPage's Activity, just try cast ((StatusPage) con).finish(); or use StatusPage.this.finish();

Comment: Wish I could accept your answer too. You were 2 minutes away :P And ((LoginPage) con).finish() gives me "No enclosing instance of the type LoginPage is accessible in scope" error message in Eclipse.